# Kubernetes - One request per container inside a pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, faas

How can i control the distribute of requests inside a pod?
For example:
I have one pod with one container that runs NodeJs Hello world with 10sec sleep.
At first without scaling, i just want to hold other requests until the container finish processing a request.

Im trying to implement a simple Function as a service with Kubernetes.

Comment: Presumably requests will already block if your service is busy / can't handle them.  Are you saying that you need a bigger queue or something?

Comment: no, im saying that the service is not busy and can handle other requests...but i still want 1 request per container (like lambda)

Comment: Ah right, sounds like you're talking about explicit throttling.  I don't know whether K8S has built-in support for that, but I wonder whether you could also achieve that the source-code level in your service?  (e.g. by only having a single request-handler thread.)

Comment: what if i use Coarse Parallel Processing Using a Work Queue? every request will be a job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Kubernetes support ingress  controller, you may configure nginx like this below:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

server {
location /login/ {
    limit_req zone=mylimit;


    proxy_pass http://my_upstream;
}
}
```

But if you want to  limit rate  by using kubernetes resource quota, 
the github issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2856 may be useful

[Configuring Basic Rate Limiting](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/)

[k8s Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)